# Macbook Pro 16' keeps waking up from mouse movements

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, sleep

I want to prevent bluetooth mouse moves from waking up my macbook pro 16". I have Catalina 10.15.2, bluetooth mouse Logitech MX Master 2 (using latest Logitech drivers), and I have disabled "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer". I have tried restarting but every time I put the mac to sleep (both by putting display to sleep with hot corners, and by going to Apple Menu > Sleep), I can move the mouse a few seconds later and the laptop wakes up.

Other than switching the mouse off or flipping it around, is there a way to have OSX not wake up on bluetooth mouse moves?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting… I lost that ability about 5 years ago & always have to hit the spacebar if it's definitely nodded off, not just on screensaver. I'd rather have the mouse move back [as I'm on a desktop that's not a hinderance to me] Also on an MX2, but this has been the same for several years, multiple mice.

Comment: Try temporarily uninstalling all the Logitech drivers as a test. macOS has built-in drivers for Bluetooth mice, which should allow the basic functionality of your mouse to work. This will help you determine if the Logitech drivers are the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Spiff. I will report back if it works.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Have the same issue

Comment: No, only workarounds; I now use a mouse mat and I've acquired the habit of putting the mouse far away from me when not in use, e.g. under the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have the MX Master 2; and my MBP Pro Nov '19 kept getting heated up when I carried it around with the mouse.

I solved the wake problem by simply turning off the switch beneath my mouse. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Abishek, but as I mentioned in my question, I'm looking for a config option that doesn't require me to physically change the mouse.